# SQL Transpose/Pivot/Unpivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like

```
key | tag1 | tag2 | tag3 | tag4
A      1      4      8      9
B      3      7      9      4
C      7      3      2      6
```

I would like to query the table and get results that look like

```
key  | tag
A       1
A       4
A       8
A       9
B       3
B       7
B       9
B       4
C       7
C       3
C       2
C       6
```

Is there any function or solution in SQL to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple `UNPIVOT`

```
SELECT [key], [tag]
FROM tblName
UNPIVOT ([tag] FOR [vals] IN ([tag1], [tag2], [tag3], [tag4])) A
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are other two ways to unpivot your table:

Using `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT
    t.key, x.tag
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY(VALUES
    (tag1), (tag2), (tag3), (tag4)
) x(tag)
```

Using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT key, tag1 FROM tbl UNION ALL
SELECT key, tag2 FROM tbl UNION ALL
SELECT key, tag3 FROM tbl UNION ALL
SELECT key, tag4 FROM tbl
```

---

Dwain Camp's wrote an article showing [`CROSS APPLY`](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/CROSS+APPLY+VALUES+UNPIVOT/91234/) having the best performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is also helpful